# JPA foreign key zero 0 value hibernate TransientPropertyValueException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

I have found that hibernate (or mariadb) JPA does not seem to work with 0 values in a foreign key.

I have a parent class

```
class Parent {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer parentId;
}
```

And a child class

```
class Child {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer childId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

So we have 2 rows in parent. `parent_id=0` and `parent_id=1`

My problem is that I get an error when attempting to use parent with ID 0. i.e. This code

```
Parent p = entityManager.find(Parent.class, new Integer(0));
Child c = new Child();
c.setParent(p);
entityManager.persist(c);
```

Will fail with the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property
>   references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before
>   current operation : com.whatever.Child.parent -> com.whatever.Parent

But the following works fine:

```
Parent p = entityManager.find(Parent.class, new Integer(1));
Child c = new Child();
c.setParent(p);
entityManager.persist(c);
```

So I assume the `PARENT_ID=0` somehow confusing JPA into thinking it is not a valid parent object.

Or is this actually a mariadb issue? Related to the fact that you have to change a session setting in order to insert 0's into `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns.

Is there any config or annotation I can do to make this work. Unfortunately we are putting JPA code on an existing system, so changing the `PARENT_ID` values is not a trivial task. (and everybody hates data conversion).

Any tips very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MariaDB/MySQL handle `AUTO_INCREMENT` thus:  Numbers are 1 or greater; 0 is a valid sequence number.  If JPA cannot live with those (and some other) limitations, JPA is broken.  (Sorry, but I get irritated with 3rd party software that makes life difficult for MySQL users.)